# paid vs unpaid internship

Tags: internship

I would prefer a paid internship but would also accept an unpaid internship.  How do you answer the question asking whether you expect to be paid or not?  I don't want to cut out the possibility of being paid but I don't want to not be considered for the internship if I say I want to be paid.

Comment: In what context is the question being asked?  If you're talking with a particular company, it's very likely that they've already indicated whether the internship is paid or unpaid.  I can't recall seeing a company advertise for both paid and unpaid internship positions.  If this is something that your career center is asking you, then the answer is that you'd accept either.

Comment: @JustinCave I read this as a company has asked for a preference, perhaps as a screening step.

Comment: @JaneS Surely the screening step would be entirely avoidable by just listing whether it's paid or unpaid in the ad though?

Comment: @Lilienthal Not necessarily. They may be trying to gauge the reaction to a paid or unpaid internship. Perhaps they've not offered an internship before, or are trying a new policy.

Comment: @JaneS I suppose, though I would steer clear of any company trying this as it feels like an underhanded tactic to me. But I guess I'm not in a position where I have to consider unpaid internships which sadly (and bizarrely) still seems like somewhat of a luxury.

Comment: @Lilienthal I have no argument there.  Back in my day we didn't even _have_ internships, leastwise in my country.

Answer (score 9):

Simply answer something like:

> While my preference would of course be for a paid internship, I would consider an unpaid one if it were offered.  I would then have to manage my living expenses differently, but it's not an option I would completely exclude.

That way you can discuss the fact that money is good, but you're open to the idea.

Comment: I would change that to:  I would consider an unpaid one if the opportunity was exciting enough. The rest of the text is fine, but let them know they have to offer something better than usual for you to consider unpaid.

Comment: The phrase "...I would consider an unpaid one..." in business is the equivalent of "please don't pay me".